# Change Cookbook attribute file content on chef sever through Bash

Tags: bash, chef-infra

I have a scenario where I need to replace certain Strings in an attribute file within a cookbook with user input from within a Bash script.

In the current puppet setup this is done simply by using sed on the module files, since the modules are stored in the file structure as files and folders.

How can I replicate this in the Chef eco-system? Is there a known shortcut?

Or would I have to download the cookbook as a file using knife, modify the content and then re-upload again to make the changes?

Comment: Yes, your second opton is the best, knife download "cookbook", sed on the attribute file, bump the cookbook version (to keep trace) and knife upload

Comment: I would suggest downloading, modifying and re-uploading (with a new version number) as you outlined.

Comment: Your cookbooks should be stored in some version control repository. That eases the pain of yours ;-)

Comment: Hi Stephen. That's a good suggestion, but it doesn't correctly align in my case. In my scenario the cookbooks are distributed with say "String1" contained in the attribute file. When the start script for the code is run to setup a chef server, the user input is taken and these values should be included in the attribute file replacing "String1" and then the cookbooks should be uploaded to the created chef server. As far as I can see, knife tool is the best option I have right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure this is the best approach. You can definitely use `knife download`, `sed`, and `knife upload` as you mentioned but a better way would be to make it data driven. Either store the values in a data bag or role, and manipulate those either using knife or another API client. Then in your recipe code you can read out the values and use them.